# How to Verify existence of a path that is processed with a for loop? - DataBricks

Tags: python, databricks

I have an automatic process that, through a for loop, checks if there is a folder on a daily basis to process its content (This folder belongs to a blob storage inside an Azure container, but it is processed from a DataBricks notebook).
If the folder exists, its content is processed, if it does not exist, it should finish without errors.
There are days that it has nothing to process, and it does not generate this folder and the for loop gives an error as it cannot find it.

How can I avoid that error?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using try/except? You can run the problematic code in a try block and provide an alternative method of handling the error in the except block:

i.e.

```
try:
    for periodo in dbutils.fs.ls("../../.."):
        #code goes here
except:
    print("The folder was not found... Continue running")
```

A better guide can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `os` module, just like as follow:

```py
from os import path

if path.exists("/mnt/dlgs-silver/migs/Delta/certificados/"):
    for periodo in dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/dlgs-silver/migs/Delta/certificados/"):
        [...]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only works for operating system directories